# Angular11/HTML - Problema com autofocus

Tags: javascript, html, angular, formulário, input

Olá, pessoal. Estou tendo problemas com o autofocus. Tenho um formulário de login com usuario e senha. O autofocus está no input do usuário. Após fazer o primeiro login, salvo usuário e senha para não precisar digita-los novamente. Nos próximos acessos, o cursor do teclado aparece no início do valor de usuário, como na imagem abaixo.

[image: cenário 1]

Porém, ao digitar algum valor, o caracter é inserido no final do valor. Exemplo abaixo:

[image: cenário 2]

Gostaria de corrigir isso.
Se possível, ao digitar o caractere, ele fosse inserido no começo do input, ou, se não for possível, começar com o cursor no final do input.

Estou usando Angular 11. Segue meu código:

```
<input autofocus [(ngModel)]="usuario.name" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Insira o login">
```

Valeu, pessoal.

Comment: Ficou confusa sua pergunta, mas, o comportamento do **autofocus** é esse mesmo, se o campo tiver algum valor pré-definido o cursor irá para o final do valor inputado.

Comment: Nesse caso, o próprio navegador salva o login e password digitados, para que não seja preciso digita-los novamente. Então nos próximos acessos, só acessar a página e clicar no botão de logar. Como eu coloquei o autofocus no campo username, o marcador inicia no começo do input, o qual já possui o login salvo pelo navegador. Ao digitar o valor, mesmo o marcador estando no começo, o valor digitado vai pro final do input. É só isso que eu gostaria de ajustar.

Comment: Certo entendi, vc está com o atributo `autocomplete` habilitado, por isso os campos já vem preenchido pelo navegador com os dados cadastrados antes. Uma das possibilidades seria colocar um evento **input** por exemplo que no momento em que for digitado algo no campo ele o limparia, pois, se quer digitar algo significa que não quer mais utilizar aquele valor salvo anteriormente, ou seja, é só apagá-lo: **`<input autofocus [(ngModel)]="usuario.name" type="text" (input)="usuario.name = '' " ...>`**

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi o problema desabilitando o autocomplete desse jeito:

```
<input autocomplete="new-password" [(ngModel)]="usuario.password" type="password" name="senha" id="senha" placeholder="Insira a senha">
```

Agora o usuário precisa selecionar o password salvo. Valeu, pessoal.